# Meteor <meta name="fragment" content="!"> appearing twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, seo

I'm using the spiderable package with meteor. I don't know why, but `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` is appearing twice, and still appearing once in the source when I use `?_escaped_fragment_=`

This is the site: [Beehive.codes](https://beehive.codes)

I'm not including it in any of my templates, and I don't see it in the [meteor-blog](https://github.com/differential/meteor-blog) source code either.

These are the packages I have installed:

- meteor-platform
- iron:router
- less
- ryw:blog
- meteorhacks:kadira
- mrt:moment
- mrt:moment-timezone
- accounts-password
- accounts-ui
- email
- meteorhacks:fast-render
- gentlenode:spiderable-ssl
- manuelschoebel:ms-seo

Comment: Have you removed the "Spiderable" package one of the default Meteor packages as per the README, https://atmospherejs.com/gentlenode/spiderable-ssl,  of the gentlenode:spiderable-ssl packge?

Comment: Looks like there might be an issue with the spiderable package. I'm able to crawl the site but it doesn't look like Google is picking anything up. You might want to look into using another package or digging in a bit more, as tsega noted. https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fbeehive.codes%2F&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fbeehive.codes%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1696j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=site:https://beehive.codes/&filter=0

Comment: Yes, I've removed the default spiderable package.